# Compute $2^{2x}-2^{-2x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$2^x - 2^{-x} = 4$$
>
> - Compute $2^{2x}-2^{-2x}$

I'm unable to notice anything here. Maybe we can square the first equation in order to get that expression. Could you assist me with this?

Regards

Comment: Well, what do you get if you square both sides?

Comment: Subsitute $2^{x}$ by t>0; is it any easier now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $t = 2^x$ so that $2^{-x} = t^{-1} = \frac{1}{t}$. Hence, the equation simplifies to

$$t-\frac{1}{t} = 4$$

You’re left with the equation above. Can you continue from here? Note that a non-positive solution is extraneous because $2^x > 0$. Finally, you would have to evaluate $2^{2x}-2^{-2x}$, which is

$$t^2-\frac{1}{t^2}$$

The key here is to realize that such questions typically give extra information to throw you off, so always look for good substitutions to simplify these problems.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a-\dfrac1a=4$

We need $a^2-\dfrac1{a^2}=\left(a-\dfrac1a\right)\left(a+\dfrac1a\right)$

$$\left(a+\dfrac1a\right)^2=\left(a-\dfrac1a\right)^2+4a\cdot\dfrac1a=?$$

Answer (score 0):

$$2^x-2^{-x}=4$$
$$2^{2x}-1=4\times2^x$$
$$(2^x)^2-4(2^x)-1=0$$
let $u=2^x$ and now solve:
$$u^2-4u-1=0$$